# Google Maps shows white screen when pressing back button

Tags: android, google-maps, android-screen-support, supportmapfragment

I am using Google Maps in my app when I run it on an Android device showing a map, but when I press the back button then it shows sometimes a white screen and sometimes a black screen. What would be the specific reason for showing a black screen and a white screen?

```
SupportFragmentManager mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```